# JavaScript & Node.js - Incorrect JSON string in controller function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

JavaScript & Node.js - Incorrect json string in controller function

I'm sending a JSON via ajax to a route in Node.js. But when I fetch the req.body in the node.js function ... the JSON looks incorrect. What am I missing?

JavaScript:

```
var getID = $('.input-id').val();
var getName = $('.input-name').val();

var books = $('.select-books').val();

var books = books.map(function(book) {
            return {id: book};
        });

var dataaddID = {};
dataaddID['add'] = { id : getID, name : getName, books };

var jsonaddID = JSON.stringify(dataaddID);

console.log(jsonaddID);

$.ajax({
    url:'/books/add',
    type:'POST',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': csrfKey},
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonaddID,
    success:function(data){

        console.log(data);

    }

});
```

Console Result:

```
{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]}}
```

Node.js route/function

```
postBooks: async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    var getBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    console.log(getBody);

}
```

Weired result:

```
{ '{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":': { '{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}': '' } }

{"{\"add\":{\"id\":\"T1088\",\"name\":\"Zynula\",\"books\":":{"{\"id\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"2\"}":""}}
```

Expected result:

```
{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]}}

...
```

Comment: Did you cut and paste or format the second weired result by hand?  It looks like you are missing a quote from the string at the end.  Also the last string isn't escaped.  The last books object isn't correct, shouldn't that be an array?

Comment: The question involves multiple parts and doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You don't show how you send data.. You don't show what data exactly you send. It's unknown what server-side setup is. From what you posted, it looks like `req.body` is already JSON string. Not an object. Converting it to a JSON again won't do any good. Express setup possibly misses `body-parser`, or you sent data the wrong way, or anything else.

Comment: If the `console.log(req.body);` really reports  `{ '{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":': { '{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}': '' } }` then it won't belong to the `console.log(jsonaddID);` that reports `{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]}}` or there must happen some additional transformation by you in between. What does the form data that is reported for that POST request in the network tab of the developer console look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going without `JSON.stringify()` before sending the data. I believe Ajax will serialize it for you.

Comment: Any time @PhilippM

Comment: @t.niese that is absolutely right. I'm forced to assume that jQuery is not using global JSON object to serialize the payload, since even if you double serialize an object, double parsing will lead you to the same object structure.

Comment: @DevYego I did some investigation, the problem is server side. I would have expected that the server would not do a partial parse that way.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated a bit the parsing in express. Without having checked all details, the reason is, that if you pass the data as the string:

```
{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]}}
```

Then the header that the content should be interpreted as JSON is missing, and the parser interprets if the parameters are pass in name values pairs in the form `key[subKey]=value`, so the parser splits it in this form:

```
{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":
  [
     {"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}
  ]
}}
```

So `{"add":{"id":"T1088","name":"Zynula","books":` id the first key and the `{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}` the subkey and the last `}}` are ignored so the value is `''`.

So either pass it as object without using stringify (like [Dev Yego](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109235/1960455) ) then jQuery will serialized the data for you and add the correct header telling the server that is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the format jQuery if formatting to).

If the API you send the data to requires JSON, then you need to add the correct header your own:

```
data: JSON.stringify(yourData),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: Thanks for looking deeper into it. I'm already happy with sending it without sringify .... just for curiosity ... what would be the 'correct header' to send it with?

Comment: @PhilippM You would need to send the header `content-type` with the value `application/json`.

Comment: @PhilippM  I just wanted to be sure, that there is not a hidden error somewhere else or if it is a potential bug that has to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying

```
var sendBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
```

try

```
var sendBody = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

you will get the answer

Comment: Then I'm getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' ... so somewhere in building the string there is a mistake